# convert a hex string to binary and send with netcat

Tags: linux, binary, netcat

I have a binary file that I can send with `netcat`:

```
$ nc -l localhost 8181 < my.dat
```

The file contains this:

```
$ xxd my.dat
0000000: 0006 3030 3030 4e43                      ..0000NC
```

What I really want to do is send the hex string directly.  I've tried this:

```
$ echo '0006303030304e43' | nc -l localhost 8181
```

However, the above command just sends the ascii string directly to `nc`.

Comment: Note disproportion with title. `-l` parameter for netcat does mean to listen. It does not send given data, but listen to incoming connection and after connection it will send given data. To send data to some server, just remove `-l` parameter.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I used the **-r** and **-p** switches for [**xxd**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd):

```
$ echo '0006303030304e43' | xxd -r -p | nc -l localhost 8181
```

Thanks to inspiration from @Gilles' answer, here's a Perl version:

```
$ echo '0006303030304e43' | perl -e 'print pack "H*", <STDIN>' | nc -l localhost 8181
```

Comment: Works great for Postgres's bytea hex format once the leading \x is striped off.

Comment: Thanks! Works great also for checking Firefox dictionaries digests in manifest! `md5sum ../it/manifest.json | awk '{print $1}' | xxd -r -p | hd`

Answer (score 37):

Here a solution without `xxd` or `perl`:

If the `echo` builtin of your shell supports it (`bash` and `zsh` do, but not [`dash`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell)), you just need to use the right backslash escapes:

```bash
echo -ne '\x00\x06\x30\x30\x30\x30\x4e\x43' | nc -l localhost 8181
```

If you have `/bin/echo` from [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) (nearly standard on Linux systems) or from busybox you can use it, too.

With `sed` you can generate a escaped pattern:

```bash
$ echo '0006303030304e43' | sed -e 's/../\\x&/g'
\x00\x06\x30\x30\x30\x30\x4e\x43
```

Combined:

```bash
echo -ne "$(echo '0006303030304e43' | sed -e 's/../\\x&/g')" | nc -l localhost 8181
```

Comment: Replacing `echo` with `printf` removes the guess work if echo supports extended features or not. `printf "$(echo '0006303030304e43' | sed -e 's/../\\x&/g')" | nc -l localhost 8181`.

Answer (score 14):

If you have `xxd`, that's easy: it can convert to and from hexadecimal.

```
echo '0006303030304e43' | xxd -r -p | nc -l localhost 8181
```

I don't think there's a reasonable (and reasonably fast) way to convert hexadecimal to binary using only POSIX tools. It can be done fairly easy in Perl. The following script converts hexadecimal to binary, ignoring any input character that isn't a hexadecimal digit. It complains if an input line contains an odd number of hexadecimal digits.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$^W = 1;
$c = undef;
while (<>) {
    tr/0-9A-Fa-f//cd;
    if (defined $c) { warn "Consuming $c"; $_ = $c . $_; $c = undef; }
    if (length($_) & 1) { s/(.)$//; $c = $1; }
    print pack "H*", $_;
}
if (!eof) { die "$!"; }
if (defined $c) { warn "Odd number of hexadecimal digits"; }
```

If you really need to stick to POSIX (e.g. on an embedded device), I recommend using [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) instead of hexadecimal. You can use [uudecode](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/uudecode.html) to decode Base64. The input must have the header format and end line produced by [uuencode](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/uuencode.html), it can't be raw Base64.

```
uudecode <<EOF | nc -l localhost 8181
begin-base64 644 -
AAYwMDAwTkM=
====
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604765/linux-shell-scripting-hex-string-to-bytes/47253233#47253233

I wrote a tool that perform various transformations from stdin and spits out the result to stdout. `cryptocli dd` will only do those transformations and nothing else.

```
echo -n 0006303030304e43 | cryptocli dd -decoders hex | nc -l localhost 8081
```

Will work for you.

The tool is open source, you can find it here: https://github.com/tehmoon/cryptocli

## Edit:

You can also encode directly to hex using my tool:

```
cat my.dat | cryptocli dd -encoders hex | nc -l localhost 8081
```